# SQL-запрос для выборки записи по максимальной дате создания

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица со следующими колонками:

```
id (уникальный) | Контакт | Тип связи | Номер | Дата создания
```

Суть состоит в том, что необходимо сделать выборку номера, который имеет максимальную дату создания. Контакт и тип связи может повторяться.

Пример:

```
1 | Контакт | Телефон | +71111111111 | 2018
2 | Контакт | Телефон | +71111111112 | 2017
```

База большая, соответственно таких контактов много, у которых тип связи повторяется, а номера разные. Типов связи тоже несколько

Т.е. у контакта может быть несколько типов связи, но они могут дублироваться, вот старый необходимо "отсечь". Не приходит в голову толковый запрос

Comment: дак вы для начала сгруппируйте по контакту и типу, и выберите максимальную дату. потом приджойните к основной таблице, и где нулл получился - удалите

Comment: разделите таблицы, создайте отдельную таблицу для типов и поле типа datetime для сортировки

Comment: @SergeyArchipov В базе и так есть отдельная таблица для типов, и поле типа datetime. Просто привел упрощенную версию

Comment: Версия MySQL - 8+ или 5+ ?

Comment: @Akina версия 8+

Comment: Тогда используйте оконные функции.

Comment: а-ля ... `where row_number() over (partition by контакт, тип order by датаСоздания desc) > 1`, ну или аналог для mysql